# jquery validation failing on valid URLs in the wild

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am using Jquery validation to validate a URL: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url

I am finding the regex jquery uses to not be a good one for URLs in the wild.  It may perfect according to some RFC however browsers and servers are not following RFCs to the letter which is not unusual of course.  It looks like the jquery validation regex needs improvements.

So far I have found the jquery URL validator incorrectly marks URLs with { or } characters as invalid.  However these characters work fine in popular browsers and are used on popular web sites.

Here is an example of a URL in the wild that works fine however it fails jquery URL validation:

```
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/amazon-kindle-fire-hd-7-inch-tablet-with-8gb-memory-2nd-generation-black/2216082.p?id=1219070629225&skuId=2216082&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=2216082&extensionType={adtype}:{network}&s_kwcid=PTC!pla!{keyword}!{matchtype}!{adwords_producttargetid}!{network}!{ifmobile:M}!{creative}&kpid=2216082&k_clickid=046dfb11-a86b-b669-52e3-00004228f299
```

Jquery validation uses the following regex to validate URLs:

```
url: function( value, element ) {

// contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/iri/

        return this.optional(element) || /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(value);

}
```

Does anybody know a more better way to validate URLs in javascript or better regex that can handle real world URLs?

Comment: http://regexlib.com/ -- or just don't validate with a regex, since even valid URLs might not resolve to an actual page.

Comment: Shouldn't the url be `encodeURI`'d and then put into regexp? As such, it should pass validation. I've always thought that special characters (including {}) are urlencoded, and that's why the browsers **do** handle them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a wrapper for the jquery url validation that URI encodes special characters.

```
$(function() { 
    "use strict";

    var urlFunctionPtr = $.validator.methods["url"];
    $.validator.methods["url"] = function() {
        if(arguments.length > 0) {
            arguments[0] = encodeURI(arguments[0]);
        }

        return urlFunctionPtr.apply(this, arguments);
    };
});
```